# Play.gif image in android without using webview

Tags: android

I tried like this, which i found on the net to play gif images:

```
private class MYGIFView extends View {

    Movie movie;
    InputStream is = null;
    long moviestart;

    public MYGIFView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Provide your own gif animation file

        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.mygif);
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        System.out.println("now=" + now);
        if (moviestart == 0) { // first time
            moviestart = now;

        }
        System.out.println("\tmoviestart=" + moviestart);
        int relTime = (int) ((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
        System.out.println("time=" + relTime + "\treltime="
                + movie.duration());
        movie.setTime(relTime);
        movie.draw(canvas, this.getWidth() / 2 - 20,
                this.getHeight() / 2 - 40);
        this.invalidate();
    }
```

Though many have said that they got their desired result.

I have put the gif image in drawable.
I am getting movie.duration() null.

Please suggest where am i wrong or if is there any way.

Answer (score 1):

Android cannot play GIF files without `WebView`. You must break it apart into frames and animate it yourself.

I found on another StackOverflow post [this bit of software from XoyoSoft](http://www.xoyosoft.com/gs/), called GifSplitter, that can split a GIF into frames. You would then want to use [`AnimationDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) to combine those.

It would look something like this:

```
// Your files:
res\drawable-xxxx\frame1.jpg
res\drawable-xxxx\frame2.jpg
res\drawable-xxxx\frame3.jpg
// ...
res\drawable-xxxx\frame99.jpg
```

Then, there is an example in the `AnimationDrawable` documentation above that will show how to display those images.

Lastly, you must load and play the animation; that, too, is detailed in the `AnimationDrawable` documentation.