# Will a .gif work in android?

Tags: android

Ok so ive created an application in android and thought it would be a good idea to create a warning image using a .gif.

The application is displaying the image ok but there is no animation.
How can I get the animation to play on the device?

Comment: What does Google's extensive documentation suggest to be the case?  Do you believe you've found a bug?

Comment: Not sure if its a bug or not, but the image is definitely local to the application.

Comment: have a look on this. http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-how-to-use-animated-gif/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Animated GIFs in Android is a difficult topic. It is an issue that has been discussed heavily and still, it is very difficult for developers to bring GIFs to life. There are three ways to animate GIFs on Android, each of them has its pros and cons.

**SEARCH ENGINE TRY = "android . gif . no animation"**

[first link i got : A tutorials](http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/)

A brief of the tutorials

1. Android provides the class android.graphics.Movie. This class is capable of decoding and playing InputStreams
2. method used Movie.decodeStream(InputStream)
3. initialize our new View with a Context and an InputStream and set it as content view

Answer (score 0):

Check this sort of tutorial [Android & how to use animated GIF.](http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-how-to-use-animated-gif/)

**Updated**

even check this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806320/play-gif-image-in-android-without-using-webview)